# Having Automator send downloaded files to DEVONThink

Tags: macos, automator

I'm trying to do this with Automator:  I want to keep my Downloads folder always empty and as I use [DEVONthink](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/devonthink/overview.html) I would like to send them to DEVONthink.

I can select the files but I don't know how to Right-click Send to Devon-Inbox.  I tried recording actions to make a Watch Me Do, but the files are not being copied.  Just selected and then deleted from the download folder.

Answer (score 1):

This Folder Action will automatically import any files that are downloaded into your Downloads folder into your DT database.

Create a Folder Action in Automator and after pointing it to your 'Downloads' folder add the following Actions to it:

`Get Folder Contents
 Set Current Group (and then select the desired folder within your DT database) 
Add Items to Current Group`

If you wish to take a more manual approach, you could create a 'service' in Automator with the following actions:

`Get Specified Finder Items (and then 'Add…' your Downloads folder) 
Get Folder Contents 
Set Current Group (and then select the desired folder within your DT database) 
Add Items to Current Group (and then select 'import')`

You can then right-click the Downloads folder and run this from the Services sub-menu. You could also add a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services.

NB For the ‘get specified’ action, you may need to check the ‘ignore this action’s input’ or get duplicates. Set as follows: 'Service receives selected ‘folders’ in ‘Finder’’.

As an alternative, you could substitute ‘get selected finder items’ for the ‘get specified…’ above. Then select all the items in the Downloads folder when you run the service. This would allow you to ignore some files if you don’t actually want to import them to DT. 
You have a few options depending upon how you would prefer it to work. For example, you could add a ‘Move Finder Items to Trash’ action which would presumably trash the files after importing them into DT.
[image: DevonThink Pro Office Automator Actions]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...I try the second version of your suggestion but I can't find the "Set Current Group" and  "Add items to current group" neither.

Comment: What version of Devonthink to you use? I'll try to update my answer to include an image of all the Devonthink actions that I get.

Comment: Hi. I have the devonthink Personal. then I think I will not work.

Comment: As per their site, it looks like you need the Pro version. [Comparison - Integrate](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/devonthink/comparison.html)